# How do I dynamically define a function to call with ng-click in AngularJS directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to dynamically generate form inputs and an associated action menu based on the model.  I'm able to pass the field to be used and the menu, but I can't figure out how to configure ng-click to call the appropriate function defined in the model.  See fiddle :
 http://jsfiddle.net/ahonaker/nkuDW/

HTML:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope : {
            field: '=',
            label: '=',
            menu: '='
        },
        link:  function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.html('{{label}}: <input ng-model="field"> <ul ng-repeat="item in menu"<li><a ng-click="item.func">{{item.title}}</a></li></ul>');
             $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.status = 'You have not picked yet';

    $scope.menu = [
        { "title" : "Action 1", "func" : "ActionOne()"},
        { "title" : "Action 2", "func" : "ActionTwo()"},
        ]

    $scope.fieldOne = "I am field 1";
    $scope.fieldTwo = "I am field 2";

    $scope.ActionOne = function() {
         $sopce.status = "You picked Action 1";   
     }    

    $scope.ActionOne = function() {
         $sopce.status = "You picked Action 2";   
     }            
}
```

JS:

```
<div ng-app = "myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <p><my-directive field="fieldOne" label="'Field 1'" menu="menu"></my-directive></p>
            <p><my-directive field="fieldTwo" label="'Field 2'" menu="menu"></my-directive></p>
        </ul>
        Hello, {{status}}!
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried the following ng-click approaches in the directive

```
ng-click={{item.func}}
ng-click="item.func"
ng-click="{{item.func}}"
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there a better way to do this (the menu structure including the functions to be called have to come from the model in order for me to build a generic form generation capability).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkuDW/1/

There were a great number of problems with it.

1. You've got a typo `$scope` typo'd 4 times as `$sopce`.
2. If you want items within `$scope.menu` to have access to `ActionOne` and `ActionTwo`, you'll need to define those Action functions above where you define `$scope.menu` (that's just how JavaScript works when you're assigning functions to variables).
3. You've got `ActionOne` defined twice, where the second one should be `ActionTwo`.
4. ng-click is expecting a method call, not a pointer to a function so it should be `ng-click="item.func()"`.
5. You want your menu items to have pointers to functions, but you've defined them as strings... even if you take `"ActionOne()"` out of quotations, it still won't work for two reasons:

   1. `ActionOne` doesn't exist as a funcion inside of MyCtrl, instead it needs to be referenced as `$scope.ActionOne`
   2. You just want a pointer to ActionOne, you don't actually want to call it at this point.  Because of the parenthesis, both actions would be called when MyCtrl is initalized.

It would probably be a good idea to understand the basics of JavaScript before jumping into Angular, as Angular assumes you have a good understanding of the nuances of the language.  There are a [series of videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5586336C26BDB324) by Douglas Crockford that can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to deal with having html code in my angular app, or directives, or the use of eval. so I just wrapped my existing functions in a function:

```
$scope.get_results = function(){

    return {
            message: "A message", 
            choice1: {message:"choice 1 message", f: function(){$scope.alreadyDefinedFunction1()}},
            choice2: {message:"choice 2 message", f: function(){$scope.alreadyDefinedFunction2()}},
        };
}
```

in a different function:

```
$scope.results2 = $scope.get_results();
```

Snippet of use in html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-div">
  <li><a ng-click="results2.choice1.f()">{{results_2_menu.choice1.message}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="results2.choice2.f()">{{results_2_menu.choice2.message}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Was based on this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdaringe/FNky4/1/