# Call a function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array with some names of buttons and names of a `function` that is to be called when the button is clicked.

If I `ng-repeat` through the buttons everything works fine, except the function is not being executed. I'm not sure what else i can try, or even if it's possible.

Here is some data

```
$scope.something = [{
    name: 'Cool Button',
    func: 'test'
}, {
    name: 'Another button',
    func: 'something'
}]
```

and I'm using `ng-repeat` like so.

```
<button ng-click="some.func" ng-repeat="some in something">{{some.name}}</button>
```

Here are the things I have tried to get the function working.

```
some.func // Nothing happens
some.func() // Throws a error
{{ some.func }}() // Nothing Happens
```

here is one of the *functions* that's to be called

```
$scope.test = function() {
    alert('clicked');
};
```

Is this **possible**?

A Quick **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVBq4/)** I made.

Comment: Pass an actual function instead of a string... then just call some.func . Also, define the function you're calling above the handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112445/how-do-i-dynamically-define-a-function-to-call-with-ng-click-in-angularjs-direct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-click="this[some.func]()"
```

or reference the function directly:

```
$scope.something = [{
    name: 'Cool Button',
    func: $scope.test
}, {
    name: 'Another button',
    func: $scope.anotherFunc
}]

ng-click="some.func()"
```

Comment: Definitely doesn't work since you have a recursive reference to `$scope.something`

Comment: Oh come on, I'm just using the names he posted :p

Comment: `this[some.func]()` works perfectly for me, thanks. that is what I was looking for **+1**