# AngularJS set ng-click function with scope variables within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I would like to assign different functions to ng-click within ng-repeat:

```
<button ng-repeat="button in notification.buttons" ng-click="button.fn"> {{button.label}} </button>
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.notification = {
        ctrl: 'logout', 
        text: 'Logout?',
        buttons: [
                {label:'Yes', fn: 'logout()'},
                {label:'No', fn: 'cancel()'},
        ],
    };
}]);

app.controller('logout', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.logout = function(){
        alert('logout');
    };
    $scope.cancel = function(){
        alert('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

If I put button.fn in double curlies `ng-click="{{button.fn}}"` the generated html looks good in the Chrome inspector, but Angular throws the following error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'button.fn' is unexpected,
>   expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{button.fn}}] starting
>   at [button.fn}}].

If there are no double curlies, no error, but Angular generates the html like this and the functions won't fire:

```
 <button ng-repeat="button in notification.buttons" ng-click="button.fn" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> Yes logout()</button>
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/y6ZXoG7F8hD7SHefsDti?p=preview)

I have a related question about setting ng-controller with scope variables with this very same example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410262/angularjs-set-ng-controller-with-scope-variables).

Comment: ng-click is expecting a function (IE button.fn()) not a pointer which is what you are getting. That's why it won't fire. The only option I have seen involves creating a directive. See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112445/how-do-i-dynamically-define-a-function-to-call-with-ng-click-in-angularjs-direct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/QE50kpfBjXy2WPvjVsJc?p=preview

I've created a fork of your code.  Your 'fn' reference were strings.  I changed them to functions, and added '()' to the 'button.fn' in the template.  I also changed where the function references were made since the definitions of the functions were in a different controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.notification = {
        ctrl: 'logout', 
        text: 'Logout?',
        buttons: [
       {label:'Yes', fn: null},
       {label:'No', fn: null},
        ],
    };
}]);

app.directive('notification', [
 function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'E', // E = Element, A = Attribute, C = Class, M = coMment
  templateUrl: 'notification.tpl.html',
  replace: true,
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      //...
  }
 };
  
  
}])

app.controller('logout', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.logout = function(){
      alert('logout');
  };
  $scope.cancel = function(){
      alert('cancel');
  };
  
  $scope.notification.buttons[0].fn = $scope.logout;
  $scope.notification.buttons[1].fn = $scope.cancel;
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="logout">
    <p>{{notification.text}}</p>
    <button ng-repeat="button in notification.buttons" ng-click="button.fn()"> {{button.label}} {{button.fn}}</button>
    <button ng-click="logout()"> Test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Umm.. I see that you moved the functions into the main controller. Actually this is only half of the solution, because I would like to call the functions from the inner (logout) controller...

Comment: Can you update your answer to call the functions in the original controller?

Comment: The references in MainCtrl controller to logout() and cancel() are defined in the logout controller.  That's a problem.  MainCtrl will never know about what is defined deeper into the hierarchy.  

I will have to let the login controller set the function references in the buttons array to make that work.  Here's a new plunkr.  http://plnkr.co/edit/QE50kpfBjXy2WPvjVsJc?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I've been digging deeper in [parent and child scope hierarchy](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). This is a really interesting way of solving it, thank you for sharing!