# AngularJS set ng-controller with scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a template (for a modal popup) and depending on its function, different controllers should be loaded:

```
<div id="MsgBoxBack" ng-controller="{{notification.ctrl}}">
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.notification = {
        ctrl: 'logout', 
        //...
    };
}]);

app.controller('logout', ['$scope', function($scope){
    //...
}]);
```

When I try to set the controller name through a scope variable, I get the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'notification.ctrl' is not a function, got string
```

So how should I set a controller based on a scope variable?

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/vomAdxYv0GC3WknopIoN?p=preview)

I have a related question about setting ng-click functions with scope variables with this very same example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409981/angularjs-set-ng-click-function-with-scope-variables-within-ng-repeat).

**UPDATE**

Girafa gave me an idea to approach this problem differently.
Instead of changing controllers, I chose to use one common controller with a switch statement based on a scope variable:

```
<div id="MsgBoxBack" ng-controller="notification">
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.notification = {
        ctrl: 'logout', 
        //...
    };
}]);

app.controller('notification', ['$scope', function($scope){
  switch($scope.notification.ctrl) {
    case 'logout':
      console.log('logout');

      //...

      break;
  }

}]);
```

[UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/S6VKG3AHbdDaHGLt0b8J?p=preview)

This is not solving the original question, but appears to be a simple workaround. If anyone knows of a better way doing it, just let me know, I'll be happy to update the question or accept any better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ngRoute. With it you can assign different controllers and templates to your root element and switch between them by changing your location.

Comment: I don't want to change location, this is supposed to be a simple reusable modal window template, that shows up in different pages on the website, and needs a different controller depending on what functionality it has on that specific page..

Comment: Than I'd use different elements with ngIf or ngSwitch directives applied to them.

Comment: Or create a directive using directive definition object. And in directive function define the controller you want

Comment: Thanks, I will check these and see if I can use them!

Comment: There is a feature in angular. I haven't found it in docs. But in directive definition object you can pass string to controller parameter. So you can define your controller in a separate file and then use in your directive by simply passing its name to your directive definition object.